# Scenebuilder border pane center area max width image (window width) set

Tags: java, scenebuilder

How can i set to the center area of the border pane a window width background image? I tried like this, but it doesnt't work:

```
<BorderPane>
   <center>
      <ImageView fx:id="backgroundView" fitHeight="100.0" fitWidth="100.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <image>
            <Image url="@/package/background.jpg" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

The image is appear but not window width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.paneCenter {
    -fx-background-image: url("/background.jpg");
    -fx-background-position: left top, center;
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -fx-background-size: cover, auto;
}
```

It works fine, when i resize the window too, i think it is the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your controller class. Just get width and height of your BorderPane and make your image correspond to that values.